# Writing value to GATT characteristic via DBUS results in "garbage" value during subsequent read

Tags: dbus, vala, bluez, gatt

I'm attempting to write values to a GATT characteristic using DBUS, however when I read back the value of the characteristic, it's not the value that I just wrote.

For example, using the following code I'm attempting to write to a characteristic:

```
private void write (Cinder.Bluetooth.GattCharacteristic characteristic, uint8[] data) {
    var options = new GLib.HashTable<string, GLib.Variant> (str_hash, str_equal);
    options.insert ("type", new GLib.Variant ("s", "command"));
    options.insert ("link", new GLib.Variant ("s", "le"));
    try {
        characteristic.write_value (data, options);
    } catch (GLib.Error e) {
        warning (e.message);
    }
}

...

write (characteristic, new uint8[] {0xa8, 0x16});
```

If I use bluetoothctl to read back the value of the characteristic, I see:

```
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# [CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011 Value:
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   7c fd                                            |.
```

Even stranger, if I make the same write request multiple times, I continue to get different values after the subsequent reads:

```
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# [CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011 Value:
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   85 18
```

Using bluetoothctl for the writes, I see the exact behavior that I would expect:

```
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# write "0xa8 0x16"
Attempting to write /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# [CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011 Value:
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   a8 16                                            ..              
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   a8 16                                            ..              
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# write "0x00 0x00"
Attempting to write /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# read
Attempting to read /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]# [CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E3_A0_42_C6_94_F3/service000c/char0011 Value:
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   00 00                                            ..              
[Ember Ceramic Mug:/service000c/char0011]#   00 00                                            ..
```

In my `write` method, I've tried "request" and "reliable" for the type option, however the latter simply timed out as I suspect it's not supported. I also tried simply using an empty `HashTable` but saw the same results.

I also tried adding an extra `\0` to the end of the data payload array in case there was a need for a null-terminator. And because I can never keep little vs. big endian straight in my head, yes, I tried flipping around the bytes in the array.

I've been able to pair and connect to devices, and read successfully from the characteristics in my code, so I'm pretty confident that my bindings are correct and that there must just be some little mistake with how I'm attempting to write.

Comment: What do you see if you use `dbus-monitor --system` or `busctl monitor --system` to check what values you're actually writing?

Comment: When running your script have separate terminals open with the following running to get more debug information:

`bluetoothctl`, `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`, `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`, and `sudo btmon`. Also the [link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/org.bluez.GattCharacteristic.rst#n112) write value option is if you are creating a peripheral, however, it looks like you are creating a central device to communicate with a peripheral device.

Comment: The option ‘link’ is not allowed for centrals. But that may not be the only issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions for utilities to run for debugging! That helped me pinpoint that my code was actually modifying the value before writing it. My code does the write in a separate thread, and it turns out the data buffer variable was going out of scope before the thread ever ran.